# Assign registry key last write/modified time recursively using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-registry, recursion

One can view Windows Registry key's `LastWriteTime` by exporting key as TXT using Registry Editor:

```
Key Name:          HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Audio
Class Name:        <NO NAME>
Last Write Time:   16.5.22 - 14:05
Value 0
  Name:            EnableCaptureMonitor
  Type:            REG_DWORD
  Data:            0x1
```

Since [there's no built-in `LastWriteTime` property for keys in PowerShell](https://superuser.com/q/1609746) (as of `$psversiontable.psversion` 5), one [has to use `Add-RegKeyLastWriteTime.ps1`](https://superuser.com/a/1609847) (kindly put together by @Cpt.Whale from Dr Scripto's articles [1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-access-registry-last-modified-time-stamp/), [2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/reusing-powershell-registry-time-stamp-code/), [3](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/leverage-registry-key-time-stamps-via-powershell/), [4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/leverage-registry-key-time-stamps-via-powershell/), [original scripts](https://web.archive.org/web/20200924092905/http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Last-Write-Time-and-06dcf3fb)) to retrieve `LastWriteTime` value:

```
#requires -version 3.0

function Add-RegKeyLastWriteTime {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName="ByKey", Position=0, ValueFromPipeline)]
    # Registry key object returned from Get-ChildItem or Get-Item
    [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey] $RegistryKey,
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName="ByPath", Position=0)]
    # Path to a registry key
    [string] $Path
)

 begin {
    # Define the namespace (string array creates nested namespace):
    $Namespace = "HeyScriptingGuy"

    # Make sure type is loaded (this will only get loaded on first run):
    Add-Type @"
        using System;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

        $($Namespace | ForEach-Object {
            "namespace $_ {"
        })
            public class advapi32 {
                [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
                public static extern Int32 RegQueryInfoKey(
                    Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeRegistryHandle hKey,
                    StringBuilder lpClass,
                    [In, Out] ref UInt32 lpcbClass,
                    UInt32 lpReserved,
                    out UInt32 lpcSubKeys,
                    out UInt32 lpcbMaxSubKeyLen,
                    out UInt32 lpcbMaxClassLen,
                    out UInt32 lpcValues,
                    out UInt32 lpcbMaxValueNameLen,
                    out UInt32 lpcbMaxValueLen,
                    out UInt32 lpcbSecurityDescriptor,
                    out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME lpftLastWriteTime
                );
            }
        $($Namespace | ForEach-Object { "}" })
"@
   
    # Get a shortcut to the type:   
    $RegTools = ("{0}.advapi32" -f ($Namespace -join ".")) -as [type]
}
 process {
    switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
        "ByKey" {
            # Already have the key, no more work to be done 
        }
        "ByPath" {
            # We need a RegistryKey object (Get-Item should return that)
            $Item = Get-Item -Path $Path -ErrorAction Stop
 
            # Make sure this is of type [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]
            if ($Item -isnot [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]) {
                throw "'$Path' is not a path to a registry key!"
            }
            $RegistryKey = $Item
        }
    }
 
    # Initialize variables that will be populated:
    $ClassLength = 255 # Buffer size (class name is rarely used, and when it is, I've never seen
                        # it more than 8 characters. Buffer can be increased here, though.
    $ClassName = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder $ClassLength  # Will hold the class name
    $LastWriteTime = New-Object System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME 
           
    switch ($RegTools::RegQueryInfoKey($RegistryKey.Handle,
        $ClassName,
        [ref] $ClassLength,
        $null,  # Reserved
        [ref] $null, # SubKeyCount
        [ref] $null, # MaxSubKeyNameLength
        [ref] $null, # MaxClassLength
        [ref] $null, # ValueCount
        [ref] $null, # MaxValueNameLength
        [ref] $null, # MaxValueValueLength
        [ref] $null, # SecurityDescriptorSize
        [ref] $LastWriteTime
    )) {
         0 { # Success
            # Convert to DateTime object:
            $UnsignedLow = [System.BitConverter]::ToUInt32([System.BitConverter]::GetBytes($LastWriteTime.dwLowDateTime), 0)
            $UnsignedHigh = [System.BitConverter]::ToUInt32([System.BitConverter]::GetBytes($LastWriteTime.dwHighDateTime), 0)
            # Shift high part so it is most significant 32 bits, then copy low part into 64-bit int:
            $FileTimeInt64 = ([Int64] $UnsignedHigh -shl 32) -bor $UnsignedLow
            # Create datetime object
            $LastWriteTime = [datetime]::FromFileTime($FileTimeInt64)
 
            # Add properties to object and output them to pipeline
            $RegistryKey | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{
                LastWriteTime = $LastWriteTime
                ClassName = $ClassName.ToString()
            } -PassThru -Force
        }
        122  { # ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER (0x7a)
            throw "Class name buffer too small"
            # function could be recalled with a larger buffer, but for
            # now, just exit
        }
        default {
            throw "Unknown error encountered (error code $_)"
        }
    }
}
}
```

Add-RegKeyLastWriteTime.ps1 usage example:

```
Get-ChildItem HKCU:\ | Add-RegKeyLastWriteTime | Select Name,LastWriteTime
'
Name                                                         LastWriteTime         
----                                                         -------------         
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents                                  7/6/2020 8:56:11 AM   
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console                                    7/6/2020 8:56:11 AM   
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel                              7/6/2020 1:04:53 PM  
'
```

I'd like to set `LastWriteTime` property to all keys recursively (i.e., to `2020/01/01 00:00:00 UTC` on offline image). Is that possible to achieve by utilizing `Add-RegKeyLastWriteTime.ps1` methods?

P.S. There's an AutoIt script [SetRegTime](http://reboot.pro/index.php?app=downloads&showfile=228) that does that in Windows 7 but the recursion is not working in Windows 10 (tested in version 1607, 1809, 21H2 as `TrustedInstaller`, `System` and `Administrator` accounts so it's not a permissions issue) and the developer Joakim Schicht appears to be not active anymore. If there's another software solution that can set last write time to Windows Registry keys recursively, please let me know since I couldn't find any.

Comment: This sound like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Why exactly are you trying to do this? What is the point?

Comment: This question is related to optimizing forensic research practices (please see PS for explanation). As it goes to XY problem reference, perhaps it may look this way to a heavy PowerShell user. However my intent was to provide at least some information on my research since I ask for a solution to a problem that (to me) appears to be way trickier that altering file's/folder's LastWriteTime using PowerShell.

Comment: I have looked into [Winreg.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regqueryinfokeyw) to find if there's a function that can alter `PFILETIME` `lpftLastWriteTime` of a key (like what `RegQueryInfoKeyW` can read) but couldn't find any. So I'm not sure the problem can be solved using PowerShell at all. That's why I provided link to AutoIt solution.